# Which political system stimulates individuals the most to strive for the greater good?

Tags: social-psychology, political-psychology, moral-psychology, prosocial-behavior

In September 2013 Germany will elect their new parliament, the *Bundestag*. On this occasion, the German Psychological Association (BDP) dedicated the current issue of their member's magazine *report psychologie* (7/8, 2013) to the question of political apathy. Unfortunately all articles aimed at how to motivate eligible voters to actively participate in politics.

The one question that ensues from the fact of political apathy was painfully missing:

All past and present political systems seem to suffer from avarice and power abuse on the part of the governing, and resignation and stupid egoism on the part of the governed. Greed and unselfishness are of course personality traits that a political system cannot change. But social circumstances promote or inhibit the activation of personality traits. Therefore, the most important question is:
 **Is there psychological research into which (aspects of a) political system would increase an active concern for the greater good?**

Comment: Re: close because primarily opinion based. How is a request for psychological research opinion based?

Comment: Not a close vote from me, but I wonder what are some examples of "aspects of a political system" that you had in mind. For example, there are formal and informal aspects of the political system. And are you more concerned with the governing or the governed? Are you talking about individual level effects or society-level effects? What kind of psychological evidence did you have in mind as opposed to argument that would be more suited on say http://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A possible research 'road block' for this kind of study is the bias that may creep into any academic article - it would be interesting to find any unbiased sources. Also, how could that bias be defined?

Incidently, Australia will also be going to the polls next month.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim To tell the truth, I really have no idea how to tackle this question, otherwise I would have done the research myself. But e.g.: in a village everybody is immediately affected and therefore immediately interested in many decisions. If decisions take the detour over the far capital and are made by people who don't live in the village, villagers will become frustrated and resign. So a smaller structure (villages instead of countries) would probably increase political engagement. Or control mechanisms like publishing bank account activity of politicians. etc. etc.

Comment: @Damien Yes, bias is a problem in research. That's what I meant with my question: it is generally assumed that, as Churchill said, democracy is the best of the worse systems. But maybe that is not true and only conforms to our western ideology of personal freedom and equality. But maybe we are not equally capable of making fundamental long term decisions (such as voting). I'm not, because I understand the consequences too little, and I'm certainly not the least educated person around. So I vote out of prejudice. What is the solution for that and other similar problems? Maybe not democracy.

Comment: I strongly suspect collectivism and "horizontal" (i.e., non-hierarchical) cultures promote what you're referring to, but again, IOU some research on this. It's an important question, and dear to the heart of my long-term research program. For a no-brainer of a starting point, I'm guessing democracy fosters more prosociality than totalitarianism. To add a more controversial hypothesis, I bet socialism is also more *prosocializing* (hoped for a second that I'd coined that, but I'm afraid others have beaten me to it) than capitalism. I.e., fiscal policy promoting equality may influence values.

Comment: What does "the greater good" mean? It sounds rather ominous and dystopian to my ears. The question seems to be at odds between asking for methods by which we may investigate how desirable the outcomes produced by any political system are (e.g., game theory), and how we may in practice optimize a particular political system's functioning as defined by such a method (e.g., policy interventions). Voted to close as too broad, but picking a direction or splitting could salvage it.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr My question makes it quite clear that I am concerned with how to discourage avarice and selfish greed. The "greater good", in the context of my question, means not to work into one's own pocket but to be concerned with making life better for everyone. That people might not agree on how this can be achieved is not a part ofmy question and irrelevant here.

Comment: Your comment that "I am concerned with how to discourage avarice and selfish greed" suggests to me that you may be looking for policy interventions against corruption, or for incentivizing prosocial behavior, or maybe both, but this was not clear (to me) from the question itself as it is written, or from any previous comment.

Comment: That the first thing that comes to your mind when you read "greater good" is dystopia is quite discouraging.

Comment: @what Please do not feel discouraged. I'm only one voice suggesting that "the greater good" is not sufficiently defined in the question as written to give a meaningful answer, and noting that an insufficient definition of 'the greater good' obviously leads to some predictably horrible outcomes. A humorous illustration of this problem: http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2569

Comment: If I could cast a non-binding vote then I would vote that this question is too broad. The whole fields of moral and political philosophy have struggled with this question for over 2 millennia; how do you define "the greater good", how do you define "political system", are all highly non-trivial questions. However, some variant of this question would be very interesting, if you were a bit more precise on your parameters.